# Any good PostgreSQL client for linux?

Tags: linux, postgresql, database-administration, graphical-user-interface

> stackoverflow points me "belongs-on-serverfault" on this, so crossposting.

I am frustrated of not having a good Linux GUI administration and development tool for PostgreSQL.

pgAdmin III is buggy and unusable piece of... hmm, software, compared to Windows-only PostgreSQL Maestro and EMS PostgreSQL manager.

phpPgaAmin does not looks promising.

EMS PostgreSQL manager can work under Wine, but such setup have a number of issues.

Requirements are:

1. Table data editing and browsing for large tables (1M+), able to jump by FK or some master-slave editing, GUI filtering and so on.
2. ER diagrams with in-place schema editing
3. Schema editing and browsing with all useful GUI support
4. Schema changes log to put into DB versioning (migrations script).
5. Tabbed interface to be able to work with a number of tables and SQL queries at once.

And so on.

Any ideas?

Comment: Out of curiosity what have you found to be buggy in pgAdmin?  It doesn't hit your wish list 100% but it is fairly solid in my experience.

Comment: Today it crashes, well, suddenly closes with that cool fly out compiz effect, when I try to delete row, probably referenced by FK. Well, I assume there are no plenty of bugs.

Comment: What version of pgAdmin are you running?  I've used it under Windows and Linux (even under compiz!) and haven't had problems.  Just curious.

Comment: 1.8.4 =========

Comment: I've used several versions of PgAdmin on windows and OS X, and I've seen crashes in both.  They're fairly infrequent, (I've seen maybe a dozen in roughly two years) but they do happen.

Answer (score 3):

Try DBvisualizer from Minq Software ... http://www.minq.se/products/dbvis/

It's universal.  It is Java based, and uses JDBC drivers to access just about any DB platform.  It's a very mature product, and has commercial and freebie.  I liked it so much, I splurged for the licensed copy!

Answer (score 3):

I use Navicat. They have a lite version that you can download for free that supports not only postgres, but MySQL as well. You can do things like copy tables from one database to another which is not supported under pgadmin3. Plus, it's more visually appealing, which is nice.

Answer (score 2):

[TOra](http://tora.sourceforge.net/) might be worth looking at.  It's technically "Toolkit for Oracle", however it can also handle MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Comment: I've already read "Community Guide to PostgreSQL GUI Tools"

Answer (score 2):

[Squirrel-SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=screenshots) is a Java based SQL client. Anything with JDBC is supported. The 3.x branch introduced a Tabbed UI.

Answer (score 1):

[Mergeant](http://www.gnome-db.org/ScreenShotsMergeant) is a project to build an open source database app based on GNOME technology.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I've used [pgAccess](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgaccess/), which wasn't flashy but it did the job. It looks like the last release was five years ago, so it might not be the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Recommendations

(1) VMware Workstation, Windows, and EMS' toolkits
I really like EMS tools for Postgresql, and would virtualize in order to get access.

(2) Look at this list of [Postgres GUI tools here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools)

(3) A cross platform tool I used previously and liked was [Aqua Data Studio](http://www.aquafold.com/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

I use for linux free tool Valentina Studio http://www.valentina-db.com/en/valentina-studio-overview 
 It works on three OS: MAC, WIN, LIN. It works as with mySQL/mariaDB, so with PostgreSQL, SQLite and Valentina DB.

Comment: A little summary of what it does? The link might break at any time...